# Set up miner R9 290X

Tags: mining-pool-setup, algorithm

Nicehash has been hacked and I know my R9 290X had highest profit on cryptonight hence monero. Where and how do I set up a new miner for monero in the best way? I used to have >700H/s. I'm unable to find a good guide that actually makes it works.

P.S. I use windows.